# Acessar Base de Dados na máquina cliente a partir de Aplicação Web

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Olá, boa tarde.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que possui apenas um código para vários banco de dados. O sistema já implementei quase todo, porém quando passei a testar a conexão na máquina cliente, depois que eu publico, está sempre vindo os dados que estão na base do servidor que o sistema foi publicado.

Teria como o sistema conectar em uma base que está na máquina local cliente? Sou novo nesses assuntos e será que alguém já passou por isso?

Estou utilizando C# e Asp Net.

Comment: Edite o WebConfig, altere a ConnectionString e aponte para o banco local.

Comment: Mas dessa forma, depois que eu publicar ele vai buscar na máquina cliente?

Comment: Eu tenho dois WebConfig. Um local e outro remoto. Quando publico não sobreescrevo o Webconfig.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é bem essa a necessidade, mas se realmente existir um servidor de banco de dados iniciado em cada cliente, você pode configurar a sua aplicação para pegar o IP do cliente e conectar o BD nesse IP. Fiz algo parecido em php há um tempo aqui aqui no serviço e deu certo.

Comment: Uhm, entendi, não tinha tentado ainda, vou tentar algo aqui, se eu tiver com dúvida ou se funcionar, eu volto aqui.

Comment: Beleza! Alterar a ConnectionString para o banco local conforme o colega mencionou não vai dar certo, pois aí a aplicação vai apontar para o banco local dela (localhost) onde o sistema está publicado.

Comment: Eu testei digitando um ip para ele ir buscar, e funcionou. Show de bola, se digitando o ip deu certo, acredito que quando ele pegar o ip da máquina cliente tentar acessar dê certo também. Obrigadãaaao mano, pela dica. Ajudou mto.

Comment: Testei pegando o IP da máquina cliente, testei em máquinas diferentes, e funcionou legal. Porém me surgiu uma dúvida. E quando eu estiver em uma rede diferente e o IP do servidor de banco não for um IP externo, aí como faço? Porque acredito eu, que o IP da base neste cenário não é reconhecido. Ou mesmo assim funciona?

Comment: Se eles estiverem em outra rede e fora da mesma intranet, você terá que publicar todos os seus clientes na internet. Vai ser um trabalho danado se vc tiver muitas máquinas, rsrs. Aqui explica bem esse processo: http://ptcomputador.com/Ferragens/servers/62338.html. Eu particularmente acho mais adequado e seguro pro seu sistema criar uma intranet e configurar seus clientes nela. Abraço!